# Facebook Page Tab renaming using fb app id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-tabs

How to change Page Tab name name position using app id .
I did use this  code

```
$facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/tabs/', 'POST', array('access_token' => $access_token,'app_id' => $appId,'position' => 2,'name' => $tab_name,'is_non_connection_landing_tab' => true));
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/tabs

According to the docs, it is `custom_name`, not `name`. Also, you need to change your endpoint: `/{page-id}/tabs/app_{app-id}`

Check out the "Updating" section for all the parameters and click on "PHP SDK" for example code.